# How to reset to default state of routes when using react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm new with React and I'm using react-router to redirect between routes. The problem is: I go to one route, change some state, use Link of react-router to go to another route, then back to last route, and it still keeps the state that I changed before. I'm working on react-boilerplate. So what did I do wrong?
Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Comment: @Quang Anh Pham: Did you solve your issue in the meantime? Maybe you could still add some code, please?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as if the route components are staying mounted in between route transitions. If this is not the desired behavior you'll have to implement some logic that unmounts the component on route change.

Here's some discussion on how that happens in ReactTraining/react-router

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4578